# Scale text on the page adding 1px to font-size

Tags: javascript, html, css

My HTML code:

```
<h1>Hello world</h1>
<p>lorem ipsum</p>
<h4>jonathan doe</h4>
```

I want to add 1 pixel to font-size of each next above text element (h1, p, h4). I've read that it can be done using SASS by adding variable of font size to the element but then I have to put the variable manually one by one.

Is there any method of doing this with javascript or jquery without me having to add 1px to the style of each element?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: How about putting them inside a `<div id="container">` container, and by jQuery or JS loop that divs' childs and increase size?

Comment: "and i want to add 1 pixel to all the text above(h1, p, h4)." , so basically you just want to add a margin-top of 1px above the h1 , right?

Comment: oh no my mistake, what i mean is adding font-size to all elements

Comment: So what you want is, above that specific h1, you want all the text to be 1 font size bigger?

Comment: yes sir, i want the h1, p and h4 have a bigger font size without manually ading them to each style

Comment: u can use the rem or em unit its all relative to the original font size   ,rem Relative to font-size of the root element and em Relative to the font-size of the element (2em means 2 times the size of the current font

Comment: in this case, you need to increase font size of all elements using percentage: font-size:105%, but this is a bad practice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code add 1 pixel to all font on your webpage

```
body {
    font-size: calc(1em + 1px);
}
```

Comment: kind sir, you are a wizard. Thanks a lot, it worked!!

Comment: That doesn't work. It will add 1px to the body text. Anything which is computed as a percentage of that will be scaled by 1px multiplied by the scaling factor. Anything which is given an absolute font-size will ignore that completely.

Comment: i see, it solved my problem when i tried it, maybe just in my condition. thanks for giving me another insight, i will pay attention about this next time!